# Any reason why I cannot take a screenshot of my app with ICS built-in shortcut?

Tags: android, screenshot

At first, this might not seem the proper place to ask this... But since I've only noticed this problem with my own app, I guess there's no other place to ask it. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I have no clue what...

As you are probably aware, ICS allows you to take a screenshot of the screen pressing `Power + VolumeDown`. I own an HTC One X and the shortcut is `Power + Home`. I don't know if this changes anything (maybe someone with a Galaxy Nexus could try it out).

My own app, Notification Agenda (I'm not going to link it so I'm not accused of SPAM or something similar but there's really no way I can post this question without self-advertising my app cause), doesn't allow me to take screenshots with the above key combination with my One X. I can take screenshots of any other app but it doesn't work on my own...

What the hell do you think I'm doing to "disable" this? My app is very simple and there's not much going on for this to happen. Any ideas?

Every time I try to take a screenshot of my app, I get this in logcat:

```
08-24 00:15:40.570: E/InputManager-JNI(277): An exception was thrown by callback 'interceptKeyBeforeDispatching'.
08-24 00:15:40.570: E/InputManager-JNI(277): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=83; regionStart=-1; regionLength=83
08-24 00:15:40.570: E/InputManager-JNI(277):    at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
08-24 00:15:40.570: E/InputManager-JNI(277):    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
08-24 00:15:40.570: E/InputManager-JNI(277):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.interceptKeyBeforeDispatching(PhoneWindowManager.java:2375)
08-24 00:15:40.570: E/InputManager-JNI(277):    at com.android.server.wm.InputMonitor.interceptKeyBeforeDispatching(InputMonitor.java:307)
08-24 00:15:40.570: E/InputManager-JNI(277):    at com.android.server.wm.InputManager$Callbacks.interceptKeyBeforeDispatching(InputManager.java:663)
08-24 00:15:40.570: E/InputManager-JNI(277):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

That doesn't happen when the screenshot works. Instead a bunch of other calls to the screenshot app and many other things are logged.

Why is my app preventing the screenshot and generating the error above?

Comment: There is a check somewhere in Androids sourcecode that prevents screenshots of some sort of protected surfaces, probably intended for DRM content. But since HTC seems to have modified the screenshot feature they might have changed / broken more. Do you modify anything about the drawing like hardware acceleration or so?

Comment: @zapl They may have changed it but why can I take a screenshot of any other app but my own? So far haven't found this problem any where else... I am forcing hardware acceleration on AndroidManifest but on ICS it's `true` even if I don't set that attribute.

Comment: Btw, what fails? Pressing the buttons does not trigger the screenshot feature or the result is a black image? Is there anything happening in logcat when you press the buttons?

Comment: When a screenshot works the whole screen flashes and I hear a shutter sound, no such things happen when it doesn't work, no image is saved to the storage either. I never remember to look at logcat... Please see the edited question.

Comment: I don't see a call to `String#substring()` in [`PhoneWindowManager.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java#PhoneWindowManager.interceptKeyBeforeDispatching%28android.view.WindowManagerPolicy.WindowState%2Candroid.view.KeyEvent%2Cint%29) and the line numbers totally don't match anywhere close so I guess HTC modified something there. It's probably HTC's fault :)

Comment: But that's what I don't understand... If it didn't work at all, but it does work... It only doesn't work with MY app, that's the strange thing...

Comment: There is some `String` involved where it fails, so I guess it is some string that depends on the app that is running. Maybe the title or something like that. I can assure you that it is no problem to put bugs that trigger rarly

Comment: What version of Android is this? ICS, but, specifically, is it 4.0.4, 4.0.3? The lines I have here in the AOSP source, does not match up, so something in HTC version is slightly modified...?

Comment: Right now I have 4.0.4 but it also didn't work when I had 4.0.3...

Comment: I tryed your app on HTC Sensation and I can take screenshots as usual.

Comment: I actually ran into this problem the other day. I backed out of the app. Took a screenshot of the homescreen. Went back into the app and it worked.

Comment: @endy That didn't work with me on my phone :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check if the app that takes the screenshot (the one that react to the key combination you talk about) is registered as system app. Android by design stops apps from sharing framebuffer, so any app trying to take screenshots won't do.

Dig deeper on that app's behavior and design.

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant at all since the app that takes the screenshot is not my own and I can't change it. It also doesn't explain why it works with any other app but my own. That makes no sense.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral He meant that HTC screwed their app up and didn't include it as a system app.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer Ok. But again... Why does it work with *any* other app but the one I've developed?

Answer (score 4):

One thing that can cause this is for FLAG_SECURE to be turned on for your window.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can use the DDMS perspective of Eclipse to take screenshots, just run your app, enter DDMS perspective and click the camera icon on tab "devices"